# Can we make Persistent object Transient again in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, session, persistent

from what I understand , Persistent object is which has representation in DB,
but if I call `session.delete()` on that object , 
what will be the state of object ?
`Detached or Transient ?`

Consider this code :

```
      Animal a = new Animal(1," Dolphin ", " Sea" ); 

      Session s= SessionFactoryUtil.getSession();
      Transaction  tr = s.beginTransaction();

         s.save(a);       
         s.flush();         //here a became persistent
         s.delete(a); 
         tr.commit();      // what is the state of a here ?
         s.close();
```